# CytoscapeJS in React: run the layout

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cytoscape.js

I have cytoscape in react using plotly's cytoscape for react, [here](https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs).

I have performed the following steps:

```
// import and register the layouts
import Cytoscape from 'cytoscape';  
import COSEBilkent from 'cytoscape-cose-bilkent'; 

Cytoscape.use(COSEBilkent);
```

And I am rendering my graph inside the component (elements are properly formed):

```
render() {
...
let elements = ...
const layout = {name:'cose-bilkent'}; 
...
<Cytoscape
elements={elements} 
style={{width:'1635px',height:'1114px'}} 
layout={layout}
/>
```

And yet the nodes retain their default positions upon rendering.  I have not yet had much time to work with react.  Is there a simple step that I am missing in order to get this graph to render with a layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import another library. Such that:

```
// import and register the layouts
import Cytoscape from "cytoscape";
import CytoscapeComponent from "react-cytoscapejs";
import COSEBilkent from "cytoscape-cose-bilkent";

Cytoscape.use(COSEBilkent);
```

And then call the React component:

```
<CytoscapeComponent /> instead of <Cytoscape /> as you have done.
```